# Remove object from arraylist by property value

Tags: kotlin

I have the following problem:

I have a arraylist  called "list" which contains objects of the class "SampleClass", the objects have a property "name".
Now I would like to remove a object with a certain "name" value, without knowing the index.

I have tried the following:

`list.remove(SampleClass("Village"))`

So, the idea would be that the instance of SampleClass where the property name contains "Village" is removed from the list.

It compiles allright, but its not working.

Comment: maybe you want to turn `SampleClass` into a `data class`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove all elements with that name, you can use `removeAll`:

```
list.removeAll { it.name == "Village" }
```

If you only want to remove the first item with that name:

If the `name` is the only property of the class, you should just make it a `data class` so `equals()` is based on the `name`. Then you could use the code you posted.

If it is not the only property, you will have to get the index in the list and remove it that way:

```
list.removeAt(list.indexOfFirst { it.name == "Village" })
```

Comment: Also works like a charm, is very quick even for multiple properties and theres no need to override the equals function. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it now, you would have to override the `equals` method in `SampleClass` to check if the `name` property is the same. Right now, it probably doesn't work because the default `equals` method won't compare the `name` property and so the `SampleClass` instance you want to remove with that property as "village" will be considered not equal to the SampleClass instance you're passing in.

Otherwise, you can also use `list.filter {  it.name != "village" }`

Comment: An easier way to get a suitable `equals()` implementation is to make your class a [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) (as suggested by Michael Kreutz).  The compiler autogenerates `equals()` for data classes (along with `hashCode()`, `toString()`, `copy()`, and `componentN()` methods) based on the properties in the constructor.

Comment: Making it a data class or overriding the equals function works perfectly! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!